# How to create a flutter status (progress) bar with a lot of lines?

Tags: flutter, progress-bar, statusbar

I need to create this progress bar:

[image]

Need help, how to create this without a library, or better to use one and which’s?

Answer (score -1):

Best use a widget from pub.dev for something like this!

In case you want to have full control over it, this is how I would go about it. There are two types of progress bars in flutter, indeterminate and determinate, I'm guessing yours is the latter since it appears to signify a percentage of the progress.

In the case of a determinate progress bar, what is important to know would be what determines the status of it. Is it a time delayed progress bar? Or a future completion progress bar?

In case it is a time delayed progress bar, that every X seconds advances, I'd recommend creating a statefull widget with a timer instance that updates a counter and the widget every X seconds. Then have this widget draw a LinearProgressIndicator where the progress is defined by this counter. If you want to use your own you could style a container to be the background of the progress bar and add a Row child to this container where you would add N amount of shapes (depending on the counter) to signify the progress.

In case you want the progress bar to advance together with future completions I'd recommend taking a look at ValueListenable! Allowing you to change the counter on a widget, from other widgets.

Hope I could help guide you a bit! ;)